# How can I move a legend on Python with df.plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, legend

I am an absolute beginner here, but I've been trying to move the legend generated in my bar chart and I can't seem to figure out how.
My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
df = pd.DataFrame([['2010', 16.8, 12.6, 14.5, 7.3, 7], ['2011', 14, 9, 4, 6.4, 4], ['2012', 18, 14, 3, 8, 2.8],
                   ['2013', 19.2, 14.2, 5, 8, 1.4]],
                  columns=['Year', 'Lab', 'Corgi', 'German Shepard', 'Poodle', 'Terrier'])

df.plot(x='Year', ylabel= 'Number of Puppies',
        kind='bar',
        stacked=False,
        title='Puppies in Training Group Successfully Sitting When Asked',
        width= 0.7)
```

For some reason I can't insert a picture of the graph here, but rest assured it looks totally fine. Only issue: the legend generated is blocking the tops of some of the bars.
I've tried to move it, but wonder if I'm putting the code in the wrong spot or if I'm just using the wrong code?
I've tried...

```
df.plot.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

and

```
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

along with many other strings of code suggested by other websites. Nothing seems to work for me!
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where you want it, but you can move it as follows:
First, your import of `matplotlib` should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Then you can change the location of the graph with:

```
plt.legend(loc=(1.05, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: when I try that, I get this error: `---> 13 plt.legend(loc=(1.05, 0.5))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @Struggling Did you change your import statement? You need to import pyplot.